# win10 not using completely using cpu power

Tags: windows-10, cpu

The win10 pc of a friend ( 64 bit i5-4210U, SSD) isn't using it cores completly.
The processor is a dual core with hyper threading, so I would expect that a single threaded process (eg a python script) can run with up to 25% of the cpu power (given by the task manager), but it is only using ~9%.
The problem occurs with different "normal" programs and the simplest case in which it is reproducable is this python script:

```
import numpy as np

while True:
    np.exp(1000)
```

The hardware seems to be ok, I visited with firefox coinhive.com and got the cpu usage with 1 thread to 25% and with 4 Threads to 100%. Also I tested a C-program running in ubuntu 16 booted from an usb stick, that also got up to 100% (per core).
Firefox is always using the cores as expected but many normal programs don't get over 9-10% (in total, equals on one core ~40%). Any Ideas how to fix it?

schetefan24

EDIT:
we also have run the C-code (that we tested on Ubuntu too) and CPU usage is again at 9% (~40% on one core)
the code is:

```
#include <math.h>

int main(char *args, int arg)
{
    while(1)
        pow(1243,1234);
}
```

Comment: Could you try testing on Windows the same C program you ran in Ubuntu? That would make a reasonable comparison. Other than that, not using 100% of core is perfectly ok for a 'normal' program: it means that there is just no more work to do.

Comment: Why should be there no more work in that script to do? For the C program on Windows I first must set up a compiler...

Comment: It runs in a Python engine, which adds some overhead - and that overhead may cause the work done to be delayed. This is mainly why similar programs in different languages run differently - they all have different environments. Some are managed, some are JIT-compiled, some run in shared spaces, some unwillingly wait on obscure system resources and so on.

Comment: We've tested also the C-program that ran on ubuntu - same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is now solved, the windows power savings were responsible for this strange behaviour -.-

schetefan24